# android minutes:seconds

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for a solution to display   `minutes:seconds` duration from `1785.16 string  android device`

In php its simple:

```
<?php
$seconds = '1785.16';
$minutes = floor($seconds/60);
$secondsleft = $seconds%60;
if($minutes<10)
$minutes = "0" . $minutes;
if($secondsleft<10)
 $secondsleft = "0" . $secondsleft;
echo "$minutes:$secondsleft";
?>


This will display: 29:45
```

Comment: Do you simply look for a way to calculate `minutes:seconds` or do you want to create a fully functional app which measures the time?

Answer (score 4):

So, I assume you have a `String seconds = "1785.16"`. Then you can do like this:

```
String seconds = "1785.16";
int sec = (int)Float.parseFloat(seconds);
System.out.format("%02d:%02d", sec / 60, sec % 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is like this :

```
float seconds = Float.parseFloat("1785.16");
Date date = new Date((long)(seconds * 1000));
SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
String formatedDate = formater.format(date);
android.util.Log.d("This will display:", formatedDate);
```

It's more object friendly ^^ And you can change the format easily !